# Entity Framework: Mapping scalar property to an SP

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have added a new scalar property to my entity in the EF designer, whose value is to be computed by a stored procedure. Can I map a scalar property to an SP?

Comment: No, but shouldn't it be a computed column in the database?

Comment: @Gert: Thanks. I don't have control over the db structure. They're just upgrading the UI to WPF.